# С# TabControl получить кнопку из заголовка

Tags: c#, winforms

Интересует, есть ли возможность получить доступ к кнопке, которая отвечает за конкретную вкладку в компоненте TabControl:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообще интересует полный доступ, но если вариантов нет, то хотя бы размеры кнопки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если задать режим ручной отрисовки:

```
tabControl1.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
tabControl1.DrawItem += TabControl1_DrawItem;
```

то в событии можно получить некоторую информацию

```
private void TabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    //e.Bounds - размеры "кнопки"
}
```

Не знаю, решит ли это ваш вопрос.

Comment: Благодарю, помогло.

Answer (score 2):

Размер кнопки:

```
Rectangle rect = tabControl.GetTabRect(tabIndex);
```

Comment: И Ваш метод тоже возьму на заметку.